# Run function on click or on enter key strike?

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have the following ajax and jquery code which is run when a user clicks on the submit button on a form. However, i also want to run the code when a user hits the enter key? Can someone please show me how to do this? Thanks in advance

I have tried this but it doesnt seem to work at all if i do this:

```
$(document).on('keypress click', '#submit', function() {
```

code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).on('keypress click', '#submit', function() {
var myusername = $("#myusername").val();
var mypassword = $("#mypassword").val();

if (myusername == null || myusername == "" || mypassword == null || mypassword == "") {
if (myusername == null || myusername == "") { document.forms["form"]["myusername"].style.border = "2px solid #963634";}
if (mypassword == null || mypassword == "") { document.forms["form"]["mypassword"].style.border = "2px solid #963634";}
$( ".home_column" ).effect( "shake" ); 
} else {
// Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
$.post("include/validate_login.php", {
username1: myusername,
password1: mypassword
}, function(data) {
if (data.indexOf("login_wrong") >= 0){
$(".home_column").flip({
    direction:'lr',
        color: 'rgba(138, 138, 138, 0.2)', 
            content:'<h21>Incorrect Login Details</h21>'
})  
setTimeout(
  function() 
  {
   $(".home_column").revertFlip()
  }, 2500);  }else{
 if (data.indexOf("login_success") >= 0){
  $(".home_column").flip({
    direction:'lr',
        color: 'rgba(138, 138, 138, 0.2)', 
        content: '<h21>Hello '+data.substring(13)+'</h21><br/><br/><h21>Please Wait...</h21>'    
})  
setTimeout(
  function() 
  {
   window.location = 'dashboard.php'; 
  }, 2500);

  } }
$('#form')[0].reset(); // To reset form fields
});
}
});
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it within a keypress function, then you can check if "enter" was pressed(13) and submit the form.

```
function submitForm() {
    //Form submission functionality goes here
}

$("input").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        submitForm();
    }
});

$("#formID").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    submitForm();
});
```

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qso2vL26/2/)

Comment: but this is only a solution to run the code if the user hits enter on their keyboard, but i need the code to run if a user clicks submit or hits enter? This solutions only allows the code to run when hitting enter

Comment: You said you already had it working when the user hits submit.

Comment: yes i do, but if took out $(document).on('click', '#submit', function() { to run the script and replace it with $("input").keypress(function(e) { then the script will only run if i hit enter, so even if the user clicks submit the script won't run, it will only run when they hit enter. but i need this script to run when the user clicks submit or hits enter @APAD1

Comment: You shouldn't be replacing anything, the code above should be used in addition to what you already have.

Comment: i don't want to end up with two versions of the script, i would rather consolidate both the on click and on enter function to execute my one script

Comment: Turn the form submission into a function and then fire it on submit and on keypress.

Comment: is it not possible to have two execution functions for one script?

Comment: `keypress()` and `submit()` are two different event handlers, they have to be defined separately.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the code that you would like to run in a function and then call that function for both your click event, and the keypress event (like APAD1 explained).

```
// bind UI actions
$(document).on('click', '#submit', myFunc);
$("input").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
        myFunc(); 
    }
});

// functions
function myFunc() {
    // place your code here
}
```

Comment: thanks for your code but i tried this and it doesn't seem to execute the code at all